# how to pass multiple uri's or more number of requests in a file in httperf tool

Tags: performance-testing, httperf

I need to do load testing for my application using httperf where i need to send multiple requests to the server and not just one webservice.
How do i pass multiple uri's in httperf? Also how can i put multiple requests in a file.

for one api or request :
httperf --server=portal.qa.com --uri=/api/user/login --rate=1 --num-conns=1 --num-calls=1 --print-request --print-reply=header .

for file i used wlog, but i am not very clear with this option. Can someone pls help.

httperf --server=portal.qa.com --wlog=n,webAPI.txt --rate=1 --num-conns=1 --num-calls=1 --print-request --print-reply=header

Answer (score 0):

--wlog=n,webAPI.txt : n - do not repeat uri list specified in webAPI.txt. I suggest reading man page: http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/httperf-man-0.9.txt. Looks for wlog, wsesslog. It has examples too.